# Express doesn't redirect to react-router root path after successful MongoDB save - fails silently - how to redirect successfully?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm a beginner with React and react-router, so I'm probably making a silly mistake.

I'm building a web app with React and react-router as the frontend server, and Express with MongoDB as the backend server. I am using Axios to send the POST form data from the frontend to the backend.

I have built a registration page `http://localhost:3000/register`. When I enter credentials into the registration form, Axios successfully sends the form data to an Express API POST route I've set up `http://localhost:5000/api/users/register`. Passport takes that data, registers the user and logs them in.

I am able to verify in the Mongo shell that each attempt is successful as I am able to see the newly created user show up in the database's `users` collection.

In the Express POST route, after the successful new user save into the MongoDB collection, I am attempting to redirect back the user's browser back to the root route of the React front end `http://localhost:3000/` using `res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/)'.

I honestly can't tell if Express is making this redirect or not. My understanding is that Express ends a request/response cycle when it reaches a `res.redirect()` call, however I have a `console.log()` statement after the `res.redirect('http://localhost:3000')` call that runs when I hit that route, seemingly implying that the `res.redirect()` call is being ignored, however when I look at my browser's console, I can see an `XHR OPTION` request to `http://localhost:3000/` as well as an `XHR GET` request to `http://localhost:3000/`, seemingly implying that the request was made to redirect to `http://localhost:3000/`. In the `XHR GET` request, in the response tab, I get the text `You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.`, which is coming from the `<noscript>` tag in React's `index.html` document. This also makes me think the redirect request to `http://localhost:3000/` is successfully being made, but something else is going wrong.

I definitely have JavaScript enabled in my browser. I have no problem navigating to `http://localhost:3000/` manually in the browser. It's just when trying to get there via the Express `res.redirect()` call that it seems to fail.

Here is the relevant code I have:

In a frontend `index.js` file:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root/>,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage/>,
    loader: rootLoader,
    action: rootAction
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: <Login/>
  },
  {
    path: "/register",
    element: <Register/>,
    action: registerUserAction
  }
]);
```

In a frontend `register.jsx` route file:

```
const handleSubmit = (event)=>{
    Axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/users/register', {
      username: username,
      password: password
    });
  };
```

In a backend `server.js` file:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new PassportLocal({username: 'username', password: 'password'}, User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

//Creating API for user
app.use('/api/users', userRoutes);
```

In a backend `userRoutes.js` file:

```
import { createUser, getUsers, getUserById } from "../controllers/userController.js";
import express from 'express';
import User from '../models/userModel.js';
const router = express.Router();

router.route('/register').post(createUser);
```

In a backend `userControllers.js` file:

```
import express from 'express';
import User from '../models/userModel.js';
import asyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';

export const createUser = asyncHandler(async(req, res, next)=>{
  const registrationDetails = {username: req.body.username};
  const registrationPassword = req.body.password;
  const newUser = await new User(registrationDetails);
  const registeredUser = await User.register(registrationDetails, registrationPassword);
  req.login(registeredUser, (e)=>{
        if(e){
            console.log(e);
            return next(e);
        }else{
      res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/");
      console.log('in register user Express route after redirect');
        };
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Or, why doesn't the browser redirect to `http://localhost:3000/` after the the block runs successfully in the `userControllers.js` file? I have read through more than twenty StackOverflow questions on the topic and tried many different suggestions, but each one simply further breaks the code instead of solving the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios doesn't handle redirects automatically.
The redirect happens on the server-side and is received by the Axios request in your frontend. However, Axios doesn't automatically cause the browser to navigate to this new URL. What you see `("You need to enable JavaScript to run this app")` is the content of the root document of your React app being returned as the response body of the POST request, not an actual navigation event in the browser.

To counteract this, you should return the redirect URL to the frontend in the response, and then let the frontend handle the redirect.

Backend:

```js
// In your createUser function on the backend
req.login(registeredUser, (err) => {
    if(e) {
        console.log(err);
        return next(e);
    } else {
        res.json({ success: true, redirectUrl: "http://localhost:3000/" });
    }
});
```

Frontend:

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission behavior
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    
    Axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/users/register', {
        username: username,
        password: password
    }).then(response => {
        // Check the response and navigate
        if (res.data.redirectUrl) {
            navigate(redirectUrl);
        } else {
          // No redirect URL was sent back, treat this like an error   
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Registration error:', error);
        // Handle error appropriately
    });
};
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: This code breaks the [Rules of Hooks](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning), you can't call `useNavigate` in a callback function.

Comment: Thank you soooooo so so so much! That all worked except one minor detail. When I implemented your code, after form submission, I was then redirected to `http://localhost:3000/register/http://localhost:3000/`, which obviously resulted in an error and displaying the `<ErrorPage/>` component, however I looked up the `react-router` docs for the `useNavigate` hook and realized I should use simply `"/"` as the `redirectUrl` value, which worked for me. Again, thank you so incredibly much for your help. I had spent probably eight hours trying to figure that one out. I sincerely appreciate your help!

Comment: Oh, P.s. One other issue I meant to point out with your code solution. You put the `const navigate = useNavigate()` statement in the `const handleSubmit = ...` statement, however in my `register.jsx` route file, that `handleSubmit` statement is not at the top level of the document, which caused React to throw an error. I moved the `const navigate = useNavigate()` statement up to the top level of the `export default function Register()...` React component statement, which took care of that error. Anyway, thank you again so much!

Comment: Right, that was an oversight. The hook needs to be at the top-level. Glad you got it sorted out :-)